# react native refresh screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a screen with multiple Cards on it.

```
sendDraft(incoiceId) {
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.0.117:3000/sendDraft", {
        incoiceId: incoiceId,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  }
```

on button click this function is called at it removes that one card from the screen.
but the card is not removed unless i manually refresh my app or save the file on my PC.

is there any way to refresh the screen?

Comment: Is your component being updated after you get the request response? You probably need to dispatch (if you are using redux) or update the component state after your get the response

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are showing cards but you will need to set state for it.

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

getCards() {
  ...
  setCards(cardsResp)
  ...
}

sendDraft(incoiceId) {
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.0.117:3000/sendDraft", {
        incoiceId: incoiceId,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        getCards();
      });
  }

return (
  <View>
    {cards.map((item) => {renderItem(item)})}
  </View>
)
```